# d3js multi-line graph to iterate multiple nested arrays with multiple nested objects

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph

I am new to d3js and I am building a multi-line graph which looks like the following:

[image]

The sample of the data set listed below.

```
 {
 "cognitive": [{
     "score": 18296.129,
     "timestamp": 1444795200000,
     "count": 152
 }, {
     "score": 17413.408,
     "timestamp": 1444881600000,
     "count": 146
 }, {
     "score": 13893.5,
     "timestamp": 1444968000000,
     "count": 87
 }, {
     "score": 11139.98,
     "timestamp": 1445054400000,
     "count": 71
 }, {
     "score": 8268.798,
     "timestamp": 1445140800000,
     "count": 44
 }, {
     "score": 11507.722,
     "timestamp": 1445227200000,
     "count": 85
 }, {
     "score": 12146.143,
     "timestamp": 1445313600000,
     "count": 107
 }],
 "blumix": [{
     "score": 8232.498,
     "timestamp": 1444795200000,
     "count": 62
 }, {
     "score": 7778.5425,
     "timestamp": 1444881600000,
     "count": 58
 }, {
     "score": 6566.0786,
     "timestamp": 1444968000000,
     "count": 52
 }, {
     "score": 4971.932,
     "timestamp": 1445054400000,
     "count": 39
 }, {
     "score": 4448.755,
     "timestamp": 1445140800000,
     "count": 20
 }, {
     "score": 6997.92,
     "timestamp": 1445227200000,
     "count": 59
 }, {
     "score": 7539.2417,
     "timestamp": 1445313600000,
     "count": 62
 }]
```

}

I'm using jQuery Ajax request to get this Object and I pass it to my buildGraph function.

```
    Graph.utility.loadJson = function(){
    var url = "../../App/assets/JSON/data.json",
        dfd = new $.Deferred();

    d3.json(url, function(error, json){
        var err = !!error;
        if (err) {
            dfd.reject(error);
        }else {
            dfd.resolve(json.cognitive);
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
};
```

This the snippet of the buildGraph function which I am using to build the graph.

```
        var x = d3
            .time
            .scale()
            .range([margin.left, W - margin.right]);

        var y = d3.scale
            .linear()
            .range([H - margin.top - 30, 10]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg
                .axis()
                .scale(x)
                // .tickSize(H)
                .orient("bottom")
                .ticks(d3.time.days)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%a %d"))
                .ticks(8);

        var yAxis = d3.svg
                .axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left");

        // Build Lines
        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.score); }); // .interpolate("basis");

        var svg = d3.select("#d3-graph-js")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("id", "chart")
                    .attr("width", W)
                    .attr("height", H)
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (H - margin.bottom) + ")")
                    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + W + " " + H)
                    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("id", "g-chart");

        // data.forEach(function(d, i){
        //  d.timestamp = new Date(d.timestamp);
        // });

        // x.domain([data[0].timestamp, data[data.length - 1].timestamp]);
        // y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.score; }));

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp;}));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.score; }));
```

The current code produced only one line in the graph because I've passed json.cognitive to the buildGraph method. If I tried just pass the Object in my dfd.resolve(json) and try to iterate over the Object by using the

```
for (key in data) {
    var obj = key;
    for (newObj in obj) {
        // Insert the above snippet here
    }
}
```

This creates a multiple lines but the yAxis has range from both "cognotive" and "bluemix"

How can I reWrite this code so it takes the range from all nodes in my Object and builds a multiple line on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can not just insert all the charting code in your loop. Your charting code does everything - including domains determination and axis creation. What you need to do is modify your code to accept a list of line objects.

For instance if your data objects would like two dimensions array:

```
data = [
    [{score:10,timestamp:x},{...}....],
    [{score:10,timestamp:x},{...}....]
]
```

Then you could modify the code that draws the lines like this:

```
var lines = svg.selectAll(".lines")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(d);
        })
        .style("fill", "none");
```

You can see that you would still use your **line** function which tells to d3 where are the values for x and y coordinates.

Also if your snippet uses a list of lines you will need to modify the code that specifies the domain, this line:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp;}));
```

will have to be replaces with:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data[0], function(d) { return d.timestamp;}));
```

But note that your chart will probably only work if all your lines have the same min and maximum (are in the same domain). Otherwise you will have to modify the code.

I have spent some time creating a charting library for my needs (https://github.com/hoonzis/KoExtensions), at the end it's almost always easier to take existing library, unless you want to tweak it in the future.

Comment: Not sure I understood the following comment "your chart will probably only work if all your lines have the same min and maximum (are in the same domain)." My min domain will always be 0 and max the max value in data.score. Also, do I need to restructure my JSON object?

Comment: I think it would be best to restructure your json object and build an array of **line** objects. Just as I proposed then the code will work. And regarding the domain, since you have multiple lines, you can have multiple max values. So you final domain for the whole chart would be something like: [0,max(allLines)]

Comment: any suggestions on how I can work with the current data structure? Modifying the JSON is out of my reach as its coming from a 3rd party service using their API. The JSON is object is grouped by keywords with supporting data attached to each kewword. The other information is required to be displayed on mouse over each node on the line.